# jQuery - Load image on scroll not working

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I have a little issue and I don't understand why. I search a lot of lib to implement a lazy load (loading image on scroll) but after many tries I didn't succeed anything.

Just a notice, all my images are generated dynamically like this :

```
{% for pdf in pdf_group %}
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="card">
            <a href="{{ url_for('list.view', id=pdf['rowid']) }}">
                <img class="card-img-top lazy"
                     data-src="{{ url_for('static', filename="files/thumbs/" + pdf['thumbFilename']) }}"
                     alt="Thumbnail">
            </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    <a href="{{ url_for('list.view', id=pdf['rowid']) }}">
                        {{ pdf['filename'] }}
                    </a>
                    <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">{{ pdf['nbPages'] }}</span>
                </h5>
                <p class="card-text"></p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Enregistré le : </small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is an example using Lazy Load lib : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qzrqEx
As you can see, all the images are loaded at the same times, even it the user can't see it

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you check the base64 string for the image, cant see an image with that base64 string

Comment: What ? don't understand yoru answer